# sudo: Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute

Tags: linux, sudo, opensuse

This command fails on OpenSuSE 11.4:

```
root@host# sudo -S -u "coreapp_customer1_d" -g "coreapp_customer1_d"  /bin/bash -l -c "mkdir -p /home/coreapp_customer1_d/.ssh"
```

with this message:

```
Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute 
'/bin/bash -l -c mkdir -p /home/coreapp_customer1_d/.ssh' 
as coreapp_customer1_d:coreapp_customer1_d
on workdevel114.
```

but it works on OpenSuSE 12.3.

I compared the /etc/sudoers file of both systems, and (except for comment lines) they are the same.

Comment: I would say not "root is not allowed to execute it", but the user you are trying to execute as (coreapp_customer1_d:coreapp_customer1_d) is not allowed to do this. Check the permissions of `/home/coreapp_customer1_d` and `/home/coreapp_customer1_d/.ssh`

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem myself and could solve it with

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

in `visudo`. The important part being `:ALL`.
The [sudoers man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) says this:

> In the following example, user tcm may run commands that access a modem
>   device file with the dialer group.
>
> tcm     boulder = (:dialer) /usr/bin/tip, /usr/bin/cu,\
>           /usr/local/bin/minicom
>
> Note that in this example only the group will be set, the command still
>   runs as user tcm.  E.g.
>
> $ sudo -g dialer /usr/bin/cu

In my context using `-g` was the whole point since I wanted to know what a group can write to with:

```
sudo -u nobody -g some_group find . -writable 2> /dev/null > /tmp/some_group_writable.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around myself:

In my context the -g option (group) is not needed. If the command gets called without it, it works on the old distribution.